# Passing parameter issue in stored procedure in ssis packages

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an ssis package where in the stored procedure I am trying to send a parameter to it:

```
exec  USP_GetExtract @Culture = ?
```

My stored procedure condition

```
if (@Culture='en-GB')     
   BEGIN 
   --my code1
   END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
  --my code1
  END
```

I have declared a variable called Culture and will set the value for culture from the configuration file. Even if my culture value is NULL or en-GB23 it always executes the first if condition only does not go to the else part only.

This issue I am facing only when I deployed the packages in job agent, it works fine when I run in solution.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: would the problem be elsewhere? Have you tried printing out `@Culture` value in a text field inside the report for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the configuration file is being read by the package?  If not, then the value stored in the package when you last saved it (prior to deploying) is going to be used.

There are many reasons why the configuration file would not be read by the package...most of them are permissions-related, or problems with the defined path to the file.

As a test, you can add an Execute SQL task to your package that writes the value of @Culture into a table and then you can check to see if that's what you passed in via the config-file.